# Problems with margin css on under 600px

Tags: html, css

I cannot remove the margin from my page. I wanted the content to be 100% width when going under 600px, I cannot figure it out.

Image:

[image]

Codepen : `codepen.io/ncatalin88/pen/JRoGwq`

Comment: I edited your question to embed your image but... you need to further edit to include code, because just a link to codepen is disallowed. You probably discovered this, since you bypassed the check by formatting the codepen link as code instead of a link.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  ...
  #gallery {
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

@stardustGogeta has the right answer. But a little bit of extra code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
  #gallery{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px:
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
  #another-div1{
    some:css;
    }
  #another-div2{
    some-more:css-here;
    }
}
```

You can set the min-width to anything you want.
Hope this sets you in the right direction ☻

Comment: One up to @StardustGogeta